# How can I instantiate a Sequelize model to be used in Unit Tests?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, jestjs

I am trying to write unit tests for a Sequelize model. I have an instance method on the class that call's Sequelize's `update` method. Turning `update` into a mocked function is no problem. I just can't seem to figure out how to properly do a `X = new MyModel()` without some kind of error. It tells me `Class constructor model cannot be invoked without 'new'`.

I took a look at https://sequelize-mock.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ but the way it's written makes me think it's better suited for mocking the Models when testing classes that are taking advantage of a model, rather than the model itself.

```
const BaseUtut = sequelizeInstance.define('utut', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  metadata: {
    type: Sequelize.JSON
  }
});

class Utut extends BaseUtut {
  async updateFromFlat(id, metadata) {

    // in reality, i modify metadata, and want to test things around that
    modifiedMetadata = methodThatModified(metadata);

    // I want to see that update is called with the right output of the modified metadata
    return await this.update(
      {
        id: id,
        metadata: modifiedMetadata
      },
      {
        where: {
          locale: metadata.locale
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

So with the above code sample, if I have an insance of `Utut`, I know I can easily mock `update`. I just don't know how to initialize the class to then mock things.

The intent of the test I want to write is simply to see that **update is called with the right parameters**, based on my own code that has nothing to do with Sequelize. I want to make sure my transform on the inputs are set right when *going to* Sequelize. I am not planning to check that the DB is actually updated. The only problem I am having is actually instantiating the model.

So all I need is for code like this to work:

```
const instance = new Utut(); // This line doesn't work
instance.update = Jest.fn();
```

I'm not sure why it says I need to invoke with `new`, when that is exactly what I am doing.

Comment: Can you share an example of what you are trying to test? If you are testing methods on the model itself I think it's perfectly fine to actually talk to a DB when testing them. I'd be leery of attempting to mock too much.

Comment: updated! was gone for weekend

Comment: its not clear what you are trying to test. Sequelize has tests on their own. If you want to test that a model was updated correctly, run the update then do a find and compare the data.

Comment: I will clarify above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So taking advantage of the `Model` being returned from `Sequelize.define` causes this issue. Rather than doing `class Utut extends BaseUtut {`, I did this:

```
// Static methods
Object.assign(BaseUtut, {});
// Instance methods
Object.assign(BaseUtut.prototype, {});
```

Doing that lets me do `new` on the model with no issue in my tests

**Update**

Just saw this was unanswered on 9/23/19. The above answer looks to be for an older version. I now just do

```js
class MyClass extends Sequelize.Model {}
MyClass.init(definition, options);
export default MyClass;
```